# Allow # in email validation in jQuery through regular expression

Tags: jquery, regex, email-validation

I have a email field in my form. User can enter more than one email id on same time like the below format

```
test1@test.com,test2@test.com
test1@test.com, test2@test.com
test1@test.com;test2@test.com
test1@test.com; test2@test.com
```

I did this.

e-mail address may use any of these ASCII characters (Client requirement):

```
   Uppercase and lowercase English letters (a-z, A-Z)
   Digits 0 to 9
   Characters ! # $ % & ' * + - = ? ^ _ ` { | } ~
```

Try to allow `#` not woring.

My fiddle is present at http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/11/

Anyone can help me?

Comment: Have you tried adding the `#` character to the regex?

Comment: Yes. But there is no use.

Comment: Who put down vote please tell the reason

Comment: Works just fine for me. http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/12/

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
"[A-Za-z0-9\._%-(?=#)=?^`{|}~*$!'/+\]+@[A-Za-z0-9\.-]+\.[A-Za-z]{2,4}"
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/abhishekjain/WwRVy/13/)

Comment: @Juhana this is not the same, look precisely, the problem is with # in email address, i modified it to handle the same.

Comment: Yes, and I was wondering why you'd use a lookahead for `#` when none of the other characters use it. Does it work differently without it (http://jsfiddle.net/WwRVy/12/)?